# Axes like wblplot when plotting X and Y in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, axes, weibull

I want to plot a series of x and y coordinates with axes like those that are produced by wblplot. How can I achieve that? I can't use wblplot.

http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/wblplot.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [semilogx](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/semilogx.html) to scale X axis logarithmically or for usual plot change its property

```
set(gca, 'XScale', 'log');
```

Change ticks and grid line spacing

```
set(gca, 'YTick', vectorOfYvalues);
set(gca, 'YGrid', vectorOfYvalues);
```

More on axes properties in [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html).